# ModuleNotFoundError in locust

Tags: python, locust

while  running the locust script in local machine I am not getting moduleNotFoundError.in git hub i am getting the below issue File

```
"/opt/venv/bin/locust", line 8, in \<module\>
sys.exit(main())
File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/locust/main.py", line 75, in main
docstring, \_user_classes, shape_class = load_locustfile(\_locustfile)
File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/locust/util/load_locustfile.py", line 58, in load_locustfile
imported = source.load_module()
File "\<frozen importlib.\_bootstrap_external\>", line 548, in \_check_name_wrapper
File "\<frozen importlib.\_bootstrap_external\>", line 1063, in load_module
File "\<frozen importlib.\_bootstrap_external\>", line 888, in load_module
File "\<frozen importlib.\_bootstrap\>", line 290, in \_load_module_shim
File "\<frozen importlib.\_bootstrap\>", line 719, in \_load
File "\<frozen importlib.\_bootstrap\>", line 688, in \_load_unlocked
File "\<frozen importlib.\_bootstrap_external\>", line 883, in exec_module
File "\<frozen importlib.\_bootstrap\>", line 241, in \_call_with_frames_removed
File "/mnt/locust/main.py", line 17, in \<module\>
from process_handler.TaskExecutor import TaskRunner
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'process_handler'
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please remember that Stack Overflow is not your favourite Python forum, but rather a question and answer site for all programming related questions. Thus, always include the tag of the language you are programming in, that way other users familiar with that language can more easily find your question. Take the [tour] and read up on [ask] to get more information on how this site works, then [edit] the question with the relevant tags.

Comment: Looks like your locust file is called `main.py` and it's complaining about your line 17 `from process_handler.TaskExecutor import TaskRunner`. What is `process_handler`? Is this something you should have installed?